# Maintain color mapping for Stacked/Grouped Multi-Bar Chart using NVD3 when the series count fluxuates

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

Is there a way set the color of a series using NVD3 when there is only one series while keeping the color mapping when a second series is added?

I know how to set the color for 2 series using .color() like so:

```
.color(['#FF0000', '#0026FF'])
```

And the mapping is correct when there are 2 series, however if there is only one series the mapping is wrong.

I have a series of bars ([yearOne,yearTwo]) mapped to colors ([red,blue]) it works:

yearOne:red

yearTwo:blue

However when I have 1 series mapped to 2 colors the colors are not mapped correctly until a second series appears.

yearTwo:red

null:blue

I would like yearOne always mapped to red, even when yearTwo data does not appear.

I have added a color property to individual bars but this is not clean nor does it auto map the legend colors.

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
    chart.color(['#FF0000', '#0026FF'])

    d3.select('#chart svg')
        .datum(data())
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart)
        ;

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you require is ["object constancy"](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/).  The explanation in that link should get you there.